# SQL Server 2008 R2 standard data-drive subs workaround

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

So after some research I figured out that Standard edition does have the ability to manage data-driven subscriptions, so you'd have to write a custom script or stored procedure to work around it and get the same result.

My goal is be able to edit our existing reports (most of them are done with SSRS but we have a number of them created as SQL Server Agent jobs) so that they only e-mail the report if data is available; if no rows come up I want it to cancel sending the e-mail.

Before tackling an existing report, I tried creating a simple test script to get a better understanding DB Mail and stored procedures, so I came up with this script:

```html
IF Exists ( Select cht_number, cht_itemcode, cht_description from chargetype where last_updatedate>'11/11/2014')
execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name=Null,
    @recipients='email@company.com',
    @subject='Test',
    @Execute_Query_Database='DB_Name',
    @query='Select cht_number, cht_itemcode, cht_description from chargetype where last_updatedate>''11/11/2014''',
    @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query_attachment_Filename='TEST.csv',
    @query_result_no_padding=1,
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_result_width = 256,
    @query_result_separator='   '
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 raiserror ('No Data', 16, 1)
```

To test this script, I would edit something in that table so that only the most recent items would be sent in the report. If no data was available, it would just raise the error "No Data".

Can anyone suggest another way of getting this result, or how I could shorten this and be able to use it sort of like a template I could fiddle with to fit in an existing script?

Comment: You could create a stored procedure that takes just the parameters you want to vary and then build your SQL dynamically in the SP. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that worked out for me. I scheduled to run the report every 7 minutes, and confirmed that it's only sending when data is present. Now all i want to add to this is for the report to omit any data that was previously sent in the report.

Comment: Glad to hear. Not sure why there were not more comments/suggestions on this. I don't think many use `sp_send_dbmail`. I use it like crazy.